# Dynamic GET parameter in locust

Tags: python, locust

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import random

ids = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110]


class TestAPITaskSet(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def test_get_id(self):
        id = random.choice(ids)
        self.client.get("/test-api/id/" + str(id), name="/id/[id]")


class TestAPILocust(HttpLocust):
    task_set = TestAPITaskSet
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 1000
```

Is this good or is there any other better locust-native approach if I want to pick ids randomly from the list?

Comment: It looks like you are picking from the list and placing it in the res_id, but then using the whole ids list in your request - str(id) instead of str(res_id). Is that unintentional?

Comment: @cyberwiz i fixed typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better locust-native approach, you code looks very reasonable!

If your list is starting to get very long and you are ok with picking sequentially from the list, you could have a look at CSVReader from locust-plugins: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/csvreader.py

Answer (score 0):

You could also store all the IDS in a txt file and then read the ID from the file. Helps if you have a long list of IDs.

````
    IDList = []
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    fullfilepath = '%s/IDs.txt'%(cwd)
    with open(fullfilepath, 'r') as f:
           IDList = [line.strip() for line in f]


    ```
````