# Use Django ORM in locust

Tags: python, django, locust

I'm using locust to load test my Django application. I'm currently hardcoding certain values in my `locustfile.py`:

```
GROUP_UUID = "6790f1e6-64f9-4707-aa82-d4edd64c9cc7"

@task
def get_single_group(self):
    self.client.get(f"/api/groups/{GROUP_UUID}/")
```

This obviously fails if `GROUP_UUID` is not in the database, which occurs whenever I reseed my database so I'm constantly having to change these hardcoded values.

It would be much better if I could dynamically fetch a group at runtime:

```
from myapp.models import Group

@task
def get_single_group(self):
    group = Group.objects.first()
    self.client.get(f"/api/groups/{group.id}/")
```

However, I'm getting the following error, which makes sense because locust doesn't know anything about Django:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

Is there anyway to use the Django ORM in `locustfile.py` or do I need to continue hardcoding data all over the place?

Related:

- [Dynamic GET parameter in locust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929080/dynamic-get-parameter-in-locust)

Comment: Do you have an endpoint that returns all groups? You can use that to find out a valid group id.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually import your Django setup by setting up your django settings module.

```
import os

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "{app}.settings"

import django

django.setup()

from myapp.models import Group
...rest of your locustfile code
```

Remember to change {app} to your app with the `settings.py` file.

Then run the locustfile by `locust -f path/to/locustfile.py`